# opening a div closing the others

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm trying to make a sliding panel using .animate function because I want it to slide left/right (jQuery allow slideUp and slideDown, but no other directions).
I made the animation like this :

```
jQuery('#slide1-button').toggle(
function(){jQuery('#slide1').animate({right: 700},600);},
function(){jQuery('#slide1').animate({right: -700},600);}
);

jQuery('#slide2-button').toggle(
function(){jQuery('#slide2').animate({right: 700},600);},
function(){jQuery('#slide2').animate({right: -700},600);}
);

jQuery('#slide3-button').toggle(
function(){jQuery('#slide3').animate({right: 700},600);},
function(){jQuery('#slide3').animate({right: -700},600);}
);
```

Now I would like the opened panel to hide when I open an other one.

EDIT: here is the markup :

```
<ul>
<li id="slide1-button" class="slideButton">Entreprise</li>
<li id="slide2-button" class="slideButton">Culture</li>
<li id="slide3-button" class="slideButton">Institution</li>
</ul>

<div id="slide-wrapper">

<div id="slide1" class="slide">
<span class="closeall"></span><!-- content -->
</div>

<div id="slide2" class="slide">
<span class="closeall"></span><!-- content -->
</div>

<div id="slide3" class="slide">
<span class="closeall"></span><!-- content -->
</div>

</div> <!-- /#slide-wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing your markup at all, you could do this:

```
jQuery('#slide1-button, #slide2-button, #slide3-button').toggle(function(){
  var id = this.id.replace('-button','');
  jQuery('#slide1, #slide2, #slide3').filter(':visible').not('#' + id).animate({right: -700},600);
  jQuery('#' + id).animate({right: 700},600);
}, function(){
  jQuery('#' + this.id.replace('-button','')).animate({right: -700},600);
});
```

But...I would advise putting a class on your `slide#` and `slide#-button` elements, if your buttons had `.slideButton` and your divs had `.slide`, you could do this:

```
jQuery('.slideButton').toggle(function(){
  var id = this.id.replace('-button','');
  jQuery('.slide:visible').not('#' + id).animate({right: -700},600);
  jQuery('#' + id).animate({right: 700},600);
}, function(){
  jQuery('#' + this.id.replace('-button','')).animate({right: -700},600);
});
```

Without knowing what type of elements the slide buttons are I can't say further how to optimize this, but using something like `rel="#slide1"` would be even cleaner/less code.

Comment: this solution seems suitable but I have a new issue : to toggle a second time, I need to click twice.
For example, I open slide1, then slide2, and want to open again slide1. The first click on slide1-button does nothein, the second does the toggle...
I will edit my post to show you the html

Comment: here is the reason : 
"Since .toggle() internally uses a click handler to do its work, we must unbind click to remove a behavior attached with .toggle(), so other click  handlers can be caught in the crossfire."
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/
I'm not sure where to place that unbid() method.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a class to the slides, like "slide", you can generalize your code and write something like (not tested):

```
jQuery('.slide [id$=button]').toggle(
    function(){ jQuery(this).closest('.slide').animate({ right: 700 }, 600);
                jQuery('.slide [id$=button]').not(this).toggle(); },
    function(){ jQuery(this).closest('.slide').animate({ right: -700 }, 600); }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with jQuery, but here is a possible way to refactor your code:

1. Create an array for your slides
2. Set an "open" property for each slide
3. Whenever you open a slide, loop through the array, and if a slide has the "open" property set to "true", close it.

Possible code:

```
var slides = [];
slides[0] = $("#slide1")[0];
slides[1] = $("#slide2")[0];
slides[2] = $("#slide3")[0];

for (var i=0;i<slides.length;i++) {
    slides[i].open = false;
}

function closeOtherSlides(currentSlide) {
   for (var i=0;i<slides.length;i++) {
    if (slides[i] !== currentSlide && slides[i].open === true) {
      slides[i].animate({right: -700},600);
      slides[i].open = false;
     }
   }
  currentSlide.open = true;
}

jQuery('#slide1-button').toggle(
function(){jQuery('#slide1').animate({right: 700},600);closeOtherSlides(slides[0]);},
function(){jQuery('#slide1').animate({right: -700},600);}
);

jQuery('#slide2-button').toggle(
function(){jQuery('#slide2').animate({right: 700},600);closeOtherSlides(slides[1]);},
function(){jQuery('#slide2').animate({right: -700},600);}
);

jQuery('#slide3-button').toggle(
function(){jQuery('#slide3').animate({right: 700},600);closeOtherSlides(slides[2]);},
function(){jQuery('#slide3').animate({right: -700},600);}
);
```